# How to import a dictionary from multiple folders to construct a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a nested directory. Each folder in sub-directory has a python file. This file has a dictionary. I want to import every dictionary from these files, which are in different directories of course, to construct a Pandas dataframe. All dictinaries has the same keys but the values are different of course.

I tried the following

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.environ["JUPYTER_ROOT"] + "/charts/"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith("form.py"):
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
```

which return a string containg the full path of the file, form.py. Check this example: `/home/jovyan/work/notebooks/charts/ahc_visits/booking_breakdown_per_age_group/form.py`
But this a string. I still cannot access the dictionary I want from each `form.py` file.

The end result I want is to access the dictionary, convert it to Pandas dataframe and concatenate all of them to an empty dataframe

Comment: How is the dictionary stored in the files (e.g. `pickle`d data, Python expression only, some code with PYthon expression, JSON expression)?

Comment: @MichaelButscher something like
```
def_options = {"name", "john", "age": 22}
```

Comment: @MichaelButscher I want to import `def_options`

Comment: If you are sure that the files don't contain malicious code, you can read a file's content in a variable `data`, create an empty dict `g = {}`, call `exec(data, g)` and then extract the desired dictionary with `g['def_options']`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import ast
#...
#...
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.environ["JUPYTER_ROOT"] + "/charts/"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith("form.py"):
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            with open(file_path, "r") as data:
                for line in data:
                    data_str=line.strip()
                    # check if the file line contains the dictionary's entries:
                    if "name" in data_str and "age" in data_str:
                        # remove the first part of dic : def_options =
                        data_dic_only=data_str.split("=")[1]
                        dictionary = ast.literal_eval(data_dic_only)
```

Comment: what if the file has other variables than the dictionary I want to import?

Comment: so you have to find a way to recognize your dictionary out of the other variables (always def_options = ... ?)...and read line by line: for line in data: